# Replace pairs of characters at start of string with a single character

Tags: python, regex

I only want this done at the start of the sting. Some examples (I want to replace "--" with "-"):

`"--foo" -> "-foo"`

`"-----foo" -> "---foo"`

`"foo--bar" -> "foo--bar"`

I can't simply use `s.replace("--", "-")` because of the third case. I also tried a regex, but I can't get it to work specifically with replacing pairs. I get as far as trying to replace `r"^(?:(-){2})+"` with `r"\1"`, but that tries to replace the full block of dashes at the start, and I can't figure how to get it to replace only pairs within that block.

Comment: I don't understand the first example. Should it be "--foo" -> "-foo"?

Comment: Yes it should, thanks!

Comment: My gut instinct involves `re.sub(r'(-+)\1', '\1', ...)` but that's entirely untested

Comment: Almost: `re.sub(r'^(-+)\1', r'\1', "------foo--bar")` seems to do the trick. I had to add the `^` at the start to avoid matching in the middle of the string

Comment: try replace `(?<!\w)(-{2})`  with `\1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final regex was:

```
re.sub(r'^(-+)\1', r'\1', "------foo--bar")
```

^ - match start

(-+) - match at least one -, but...

\1 - an equal number must exist outside the capture group.

and finally, replace with that number of hyphens, effectively cutting the number of hyphens in half.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
print re.sub(r'\--', '',"--foo")
print re.sub(r'\--', '',"-----foo")
```

Output:

```
foo
-foo
```

**EDIT** this answer is for the OP before it was completely edited and changed.

Comment: Hey sorry, I messed up the examples. I've updated them so that they reflect what I'm actually looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's it all written out for anyone else who comes this way.

```
>>> foo = '---foo'
>>> bar = '-----foo'
>>> foobar = 'foo--bar'
>>> foobaz = '-----foo--bar'
>>> re.sub('^(-+)\\1', '-', foo)
'-foo'
>>> re.sub('^(-+)\\1', '-', bar)
'---foo'
>>> re.sub('^(-+)\\1', '-', foobar)
'foo--bar'
>>> re.sub('^(-+)\\1', '-', foobaz)
'--foo--bar'
```

The pattern for `re.sub()` is:

```
re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)
```

therefore in this case we want to replace `--` with `-`. HOWEVER, the issue comes when we have `--` that we don't want to replace, given by some circumstances.
In this case we only want to match `--` at the beginning of a string. In regular expressions for python, the `^` character, when used in the `pattern` string, will only match the given pattern at the beginning of the string - just what we were looking for!

[**Note that the `^` character behaves differently when used within square brackets.**](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions)

> Square brackets can be used to indicate a set of chars, so [abc] matches 'a' or 'b' or 'c'... An up-hat (^) at the start of a square-bracket set inverts it, so [^ab] means any char except 'a' or 'b'.

Getting back to what we were talking about. The parenthesis in the `pattern` represent a "group," this group can then be referenced with the `\\1`, meaning the first group. If there was a second set of parenthesis, we could then reference that sub-pattern with `\\2`. The extra `\` is to escape the next slash. This pattern can also be written with `re.sub(r'^(-+)\1', '-', foo)` forcing python to interpret the string as a raw string, as denoted with the `r` preceding the pattern, thereby eliminating the need to escape special characters.

Now that the pattern is all set up, you just make the `replacement` whatever you want to replace the pattern with, and put in the `string` that you are searching through.

[A link that I keep handy when dealing with regular expressions, is Google's developer's notes on them.](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions)

Comment: Uh...`In [2]: re.sub(r'^(-+)\1', '-', "----foo") ` -> `Out[2]: '-foo'`

Comment: That was my mistake in typing. Fixed. Thanks for catching that.